# Как инициализировать базу данных postgresql в Docker при первом запуске

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring, spring-boot

Имею докеризованные сервисы Spring Boot + Angular + Spring Boot, после их запуска в докере, необходимо инициализировать базу данных только один раз. Как это можно было бы сделать? Spring Boot по идее должен сам создать все базы, но нужно занести в базу несколько ролей для пользователей для корректной работы сервисов.

Comment: В официальном описании образа postgresql для docker написано про инициализацию БД. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres Раздел Initialization scripts. Собственно вам надо создать свой образ на основе postgresql и поместить в него скрипты инициализации

Comment: По идее Postgress это отдельное приложение. Собственно в докере или нет вы поднимаете сервер баз данных и для приложения (в докере или нет) вы подключаетесь к обычной базе данных.

Comment: инициализация такая же как будто подключились к локальному серверу базы

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону liquibase, думаю это решит все ваши проблемы по управлению БД